# Are the hyphae in mushrooms unicellular or multi-cellular?:

Tags: mycology

The mycelium is just a collection of hyphae.

Are these hyphae unicellular or multicellular?

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. This seems like a [homework question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) and these require that you show you have tried to find an answer yourself.

Comment: The haphae of mushroom are multicellular

Comment: @Michael_A I got the answer